# extract and print all occurrences of disk file (.img) from a configuration file

Tags: awk, sed, split, grep

I have vm configuration files from which I need to print all the disks (26 alphanumeric characters followed by .img) existing within each file.

here is an extract of one of the files

```
[root@~]# cat demo_vm.cfg
disk = ['file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb00000300007b8afb76a3377693/VirtualDisks/0004fb0000120000a17dfe12ac74818f.img,xvda,w', 'file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb00000300007b8afb76a3377693/VirtualDisks/0004fb0000120000e66ace31dac64d98.img,xvdb,w', 'file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb00000300007b8afb76a3377693/VirtualDisks/0004fb000012000082fbb45a02e24096.img,xvdd,w']
```

I want to extract  the below (all references of 26alphanum.img in the file) :

```
0004fb0000120000a17dfe12ac74818f.img
0004fb0000120000e66ace31dac64d98.img
0004fb000012000082fbb45a02e24096.img
```

some files have 3 disks some have only one for which I usually run this and have what I want but in case of multiple occurrences I can only print the first one.

```
# awk -F [/,] '/disk/ { print $6}' demo_vm.cfg
0004fb0000120000a17dfe12ac74818f.img
```

Thanks in advance I spent hours trying splits and regex patterns without conclusive result.
This is my first question in SOverflow.

**EDIT**

here are the 3 types of content put in separate files  (1= one 26[alnum].img occurrence, 2= two  26[alnum].img  occurrences  , 3= three 26[alnum].img occurrences )

```
# cat demo_vm_1.cfg
disk = ['file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb00000300007b8afb76a3377693/VirtualDisks/0004fb000012000065a82a4df5e7112b.img,xvda,w']
```

```
[root ~]# cat demo_vm_2.cfg
disk = ['file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb0000030000a079ca25909e5455/VirtualDisks/0004fb0000120000822cb8b0602ee042.img,xvda,w', 'file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb0000030000a079ca25909e5455/VirtualDisks/0004fb000012000073d5fd864a0ba6b1.img,xvdb,w']
```

```
# cat demo_vm_3.cfg
disk = ['file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb00000300007b8afb76a3377693/VirtualDisks/0004fb0000120000a17dfe12ac74818f.img,xvda,w', 'file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb00000300007b8afb76a3377693/VirtualDisks/0004fb0000120000e66ace31dac64d98.img,xvdb,w', 'file:/OVS/Repositories/0004fb00000300007b8afb76a3377693/VirtualDisks/0004fb000012000082fbb45a02e24096.img,xvdd,w']
```

- Initial script

my initial script that creates the remove commands for the .cfg files and the pointed images inside each of them had a problem when the cfg had more than one disk reference. I guess I can adapt it now to use grep -Eo instead of awk

```
  
strings=(`find  /vm_backup/VirtualMachines/*/vm.cfg`)                                                             
for i in "${strings[@]}"; do                                                                                      
echo "rm -f $i" >> drop_vm_final.sh                                                                               
awk -F [/,] '/disk/ { print $6}' "$i" | awk '{print "rm -f  /vm_backup/VirtualDisks/"$0}'  >>drop_vm_bkp_final.sh 
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]{26}\.img' file
0000120000a17dfe12ac74818f.img
0000120000e66ace31dac64d98.img
000012000082fbb45a02e24096.img
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that that doesn't work for.

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton. It worked for each cases whathere I had one or more occurences of the virtual disk (xx.img).

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following based on your shown samples.

```
awk '
match($0,/[[:alnum:]]{26}\.img/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

OR to get all matched values in a single line try following.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/[[:alnum:]]{26}\.img/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  while(match($0,/[[:alnum:]]{26}\.img/)){   ##Running while loop to match alpha numerics 26 in number followed by .img if this match found then do following.
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)          ##Printing matched sub string of that matched regex from current line.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)             ##Saving rest of the line(after matched string) to current line here.
  }
}' Input_file                                ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code

> `awk -F [/,] '/disk/ { print $6}' demo_vm.cfg`

you can complete the `print` adding `$14` and `$22`

```
awk -F [/,] '{ print $6,$14,$22}' OFS='\n' demo_vm.cfg
0004fb0000120000a17dfe12ac74818f.img
0004fb0000120000e66ace31dac64d98.img
0004fb000012000082fbb45a02e24096.img
```

Comment: that would work cleanly for files that have an array of the elements but not for those which have 2 or one element only as it'll create additional empty lines for  $14 and $22 if the columns are null . 

---
[root@~]# awk -F [/,] '{ print $6,$14,$22}' OFS='\n' demo_vm_1.cfg
0004fb000012000065a82a4df5e7112b.img
3 empt lines 
[root@~]#